# How can I get a CSS/jQuery animated menu similar to ajusto.com?

Tags: jquery, css

[ajusto.com] has this slick menu on the right side with circles and menu that scales up when you hover. I think this is done using just CSS. Or is JavaScript invovled too? Either way, how can I get this effect?

Comment: post as screens or codes rather pointing to a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by looking at the source libraries you can see it is definitely a combination of css/js. However this is a common design pattern and you can see an implementation of it here in one of the more popular "fullpage scroll" plugins:

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/